# RuntimeError Error in Flask python on Post

Tags: python, flask

my code:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template,request, redirect

@app.route("/wait", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def wait():
    print(5)
    return render_template("wait")


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form
        print(data["theme"])
        print(data["subreddit"])
        return redirect("/wait")
    else:
        return render_template("index.html")
```

my error:
RuntimeError: Attempt to access app outside of a relevant context

Comment: Can you further explain what causes this error?

Comment: when I click the SUBMIT button it's not redirect and print the data and error

Comment: Can you copy-paste the entire error output?

Comment: What submit button? What is supposed to happen? Please show all relevant code

Comment: @C_Z_ 
https://pastebin.com/Z7UAhnS3

Comment: @StrangeSorcerer
@app.route("/wait", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def wait():
    print(5)
    return render_template("wait")

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form
        print(data["theme"])
        print(data["subreddit"])
        return redirect("/wait")
    else:
     return render_template("index.html")

index: https://pastebin.com/tpV43HXZ

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to instantiate app in your code. Add this line under your import:

`app = Flask(__name__)`